# Fixed footer for bootstrap template with side navigation bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to built a chrome app and decided to use the theme [SB Admin 2](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) for this purpose. I modified the theme to look something like what is show in the image above. The three boxes represents three bootstrap rows. I want row 3 to be fixed to the bottom of the page.Tried suggestions i got from stack overflow[added class "navbar-fixed-bottom" to the row], was able to get the row fixed to the bottom of the page but the footer was overflowing to the left side navigation bar.

[image: error]

What can be done to achieve this.

Comment: Can you share the code or JSFiddle to review?

Comment: The code is not running properly on JSFiddle. I will update once i figure that out.

Comment: i have uploaded the code to JSfiddle. The app is not rendered properly. Dont know why. Not really good at CSS/JS. You may refer to the sb-admin-2 bootstrap theme as well mentioned in the question. Following is the link ot JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Lbw7a4ag/

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the "left" for the footer. But without any code, we can't help you and we need to guess.

```css
.footer
{
  left: 200px; /* Use the width of your left menu */
}
```